# Nifi: How to make write and check operations in file in one thread (processor)?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi, file-locking

How  to make only one point (Processor or Service) that will write the file and make it working in single thread, in my  case  i  have   workflow  like  this executescript1(single thread  processor with  write  operations)->updateAttribute->InvokeHttpProcessor->executescript1(single  thread  processor with  check  operations (it  is  the  first  processor))  i  have  tried  the  code  below  but  it  nor   fulfills sucessfully neither  trows exception,

**WHAT  SHOULD  I  CHANGE?**

here is  my  code:

```
   File file = new File("C:/Users/Desktop/test/conf.xml");
        String content = "";
        BufferedReader s;
        BufferedWriter w;
        RandomAccessFile ini= new RandomAccessFile(file, "rwd");
        FileLock lock= ini.getChannel().lock();

        try {
         def flowFile=session.get();
         if(flowFile==null){

                String sCurrentLine;
            s = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8"));


            while ((sCurrentLine = s.readLine()) != null) {
                content += sCurrentLine;
            }
            ini.seek(0);

              def flowFile1=session.create()
                flowFile1 = session.putAttribute(flowFile1, "filename", "conf.xml");
                session.write(flowFile1, new StreamCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(InputStream inputStream1, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {

                        outputStream.write(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                    }

                });


                session.transfer(flowFile1,REL_SUCCESS);

             def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(content);
             xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'run'}.each{ it.replaceBody 'false'}
            def newxml=XmlUtil.serialize(xml);

            String data =newxml;

            if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                ini.setLength(0);
                w = new BufferedWriter(Channels.newWriter(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8"));
                w.write(data);
                lock.release();
                w.close();




            }
            }


            else{
            def   serviceName=flowFile.getAttribute('serviceName');
            def date=flowFile.getAttribute('filename').substring(0,10);
            if(serviceName=='Decl'){
          def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(content)
            for(int i=0;i<names.size();i++) {
                date = names.get(i).substring(0, 10);
                xml.RS.Decl.details.findAll({ p ->
                    p.runAs[0].text() == "false" && p.start[0].text() == date.toString()
                }).each({ p ->
                    p.start[0].value = addDays( p.start[0].text())
                    p.runAs[0].value = "true"
                })
            }
            def newXml=  groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( xml )

            data = newXml.toString()
            if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                 ini.setLength(0);
                w = new BufferedWriter(Channels.newWriter(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8"));
                w.write(data);
                    lock.release();
                w.close();


            }
            }
            else  if(serviceName=='TaxyFee'){
              def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(content)
            for(int i=0;i<names.size();i++) {
                date = names.get(i).substring(0, 10);
                xml.RS.TaxyFee.details.findAll({ p ->
                    p.runAs[0].text() == "false" && p.start[0].text() == date.toString()
                }).each({ p ->
                    p.start[0].value = addDays( p.start[0].text())
                    p.runAs[0].value = "true"
                })
            }
            def newXml=  groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( xml )

            data = newXml.toString()
            if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                 ini.setLength(0);
                w = new BufferedWriter(Channels.newWriter(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8"));
                w.write(data);
                    lock.release();
                w.close();


            }
            }
            }



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(50000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch(OverlappingFileLockException e){ TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(50000);
            lock.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            //lock.release();
            ini.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

set on the "scheduling" tab of the processor properties `Concurrent Tasks = 1`.

so only one instance of the processor will be running at the same time.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#scheduling-tab